# How to optimize this query with repeated subqueries?

Tags: database, sqlite, postgresql

I have this query which answers this question correctly:
What is the name of the movie that has the highest average rating?

```
select title 
from (
   select movies.title, avg(rating) avgrating 
   from movies, rentals 
   where movies.movieid = rentals.movieid 
   group by movies.title
) a 
where avgrating = (select max(avgrating) 
                   from (select movies.title, avg(rating) avgrating 
                   from movies, rentals 
                   where movies.movieid=rentals.movieid 
                   group by movies.title) b) 
order by title desc
```

Only thing is that it takes several minutes to run on my large database. I can't think of how to make this faster. Basically the subqueries a and b are equivalent, but as far as I know, I have to repeat it since the where clause can't see the 'a' subquery. **IMPORTANT: there can be a tie for the highest average rating, and the query must return as many titles as there are in the tie.**
I should also mention that the join is necessary since the title is in the movies table and the rating is in the rentals table.

```
Movies (
    movieId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT,
    year INTEGER
)

Rentals (
    cardNo INTEGER,
    movieId INTEGER,
    date DATE,
    rating INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(cardNo, movieID, date),
    FOREIGN KEY (cardNo) REFERENCES Customers,
    FOREIGN KEY (movieId) REFERENCES Movies
)
```

Comment: Which database? [tag:sqlite] or [tag:postgresql]?

Comment: What is the primary key for movies, `movieid` or `title` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could run the sub-query only once using a common table expression:

```
with avg_ratings as (
   select movies.title, 
          avg(rentals.rating) as avgrating 
   from movies
     join rentals on movies.movieid = rentals.movieid 
   group by movies.title
)    
select title 
from avg_ratings 
where avgrating = (select max(avgrating) from avg_ratings);
```

This can also be written using a window function:

```
with avg_ratings as (
   select movies.title, 
          avg(rentals.rating) as avgrating 
   from movies
     join rentals on movies.movieid = rentals.movieid 
   group by movies.title
)    
select title
from (
   select title, 
          avgrating,
          dense_rank() over (order by avgrating desc) as rating_rank
   from avg_ratings
) t
where rating_rank = 1;
```

Not sure which version is faster though.

---

If you still have performance problems, you will need to post the definition of the tables, their indexes and the execution plan (See here for more information on how to post performance related problems: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions)

Comment: that's not right. this is returning some random titles, not the top rated. the problem with using a window function is that it returns the same number of rows as the original relation.

Comment: @db-user: I incorrectly had a `partition by` in my first version, please see my edit. I'm pretty sure that the condition `where rating_rank = 1` only returns the highest rating. I have also added a version that matches your query but without repeating the sub-select.

Comment: those two are twice as fast on postgres. however, sqlite doesn't support the with clause and i need this to run on sqlite

Comment: @db-user: sorry I didn't see the SQLite tag. No idea how to tune it there (I never used it). In my experience there is no such thing as DBMS independent statements - if they really are it only means they are equally slow on all DBMS.